# Cannot login to sharepoint site with https protocol

Tags: alternate-access-mapping

I have SharePoint 2010 site. I have changed AAM URL. After changing, non admin user is able to login with HTTP while using HTTPS he gets login prompts. Any idea?

Comment: Test to add the adress (https) to trusted sites in the browser.

Comment: already added but same problem